# Cross browser vertical center text

Tags: html, css, macos, cross-browser, vertical-alignment

#### Question

I'm trying to vertically center a letter with a big font-size cross browser. It's more difficult that what it seems apparently, since every single approach i've tried (line-height, display:table-cell, transform: translate...) fails with big font-size. The problem exist only in OS X.

I've been trying to resolve this behavior problem for quite some time now, here's a solution that works on Safari only:

```css
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #2b2b2b;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 200px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>O</div>
```

Here's a [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yyooeZ) with the code.

Here's a result screenshot in **OS X 10.10** with both Safari, Chrome and Firefox:
[image: Safari, Chrome and Firefox Result]

#### Update

After hours of extensive testing, i've managed to identify the origin of the problem, the font-family helvetica. On windows the font family does not exist, so the font loaded is only arial or a sans-serif. On OS X helvetica is present, but the font-family differs in the three browser. As i removed the font-family, the letter was vertically-aligned by the line-height correctly. But now, i'd love to understand why is this bug present in the first place.

Here's a codepen with the new code: [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yyooeZ)

```css
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #2b2b2b;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 200px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>O</div>
```

Comment: Just took a look in Crome and FireFox (windows machine), but both show same and are aligned properly.

Comment: Hello, first of all thank you for uploading the image. I've just edited the question: i've looked up on a virtual machine of XP and seems fine, but on mac OS X has the problem described.

Comment: It's also good for me (FF 35.0.1 W7x64)

Comment: It's fine on my windows 7 chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this is right, but I removed the line height and added padding instead e.g. **padding: 30px 0 0 0;** seemed to do it for me. Not entirely sure if this is what you wanted.

Comment: Hello, i've tried your solution but it does not seem to work. Here's a codepen whit the code: [link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jELapz).
As you can see, the padding adds space on the top, not actually centering the letter. If you try this codepen on safari and firefox you'll notice immediately the differences.

Answer (score 0):

```
           try this fiddle code :
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x25wh1ym/1/

```
div {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #2b2b2b;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 200px;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
}


span {
    height: 100vh;
    line-height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
}<div><span>O</span></div>
```

Comment: Hello, even if with more height the letter seems to be centered, as you reduce said height you'll end up with the same result. Here's a file with it: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/x25wh1ym/2/).

Comment: ok try this: now i given the font size to span. its will be always at center until it will not  reach at the same height of text. please see the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/x25wh1ym/3/

Comment: I've updated the question: if you remove the font-family helvetica it works just fine. Now i would love to understand why said font is so different in the three browsers.